# Rotating image via CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on an app that uses Bootstrap. You can see it for yourself [here](http://www.bootply.com/sFQhsmcEUZ). When a user clicks a link, I want it to rotate. The code is very small. It looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <ul class="list-inline">
    <li><button class="btn btn-link"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></button></li>
    <li><h5>category</h5></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When a user clicks the "v" I want it to animate from "v" to ">". In other words, I want the chevron to rotate counter-clockwise 90 degrees when someone clicks it. After looking at the powerful features in CSS 3, it looks like there is a way to do this using pure CSS. Am I correct, if so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/ZfIyvBoSwE)

```
<div class="form-group">
  <ul class="list-inline">
    <li><button class="btn btn-link"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></button></li>
    <li><h5>category</h5></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
   $('.glyphicon').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-right');
  });
```

Comment: Instead of setting a flag and doing removeClass and addClass, you could also do a single `toggleClass` with both the chevron-right and the chevron-down. As long as initially only one class was used, it will always add one and remove the other when using toggle.

Comment: +1. Agree with Stephan's point there. Could be simplified like [here](http://www.bootply.com/ZfIyvBoSwE). Please feel free to use the demo in the answer if you wish to.

Answer (score 2):

To rotate an element using CSS you can simply use `transform: rotate(-90deg)`

However, this will not rotate it on click just yet. You will probably need javascript for that. One way to do it (using jquery, since bootstrap already requires it):

CSS:

```
.rotated {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

JS:

```
$('.yourElement').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('rotated');
});
```

The 'toggleClass' will make sure the rotation is reverted when you click it again. Otherwise, just use 'addClass' to only use it once.

**edit**

As pointed out by Harry, you could also use the already present 'icon-chevron-right' in a similar fashion:

```
$('.yourElement').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('icon-chevron-down icon-chevron-right');
});
```

As long as your html started with only one of those two classes, this code will always remove one and add the other.

Comment: There should already be a class named `glyphicon-chevron-right` for the rotated version, so that can also be used. Nothing wrong with the current answer, just that it would reduce a few extra lines of code :)

Comment: I completely overlooked that, good point. Jake's answer, while not very pretty, covers that too.

Comment: Thanks, I figured I might as well update my answer with your solution since I think it's a better one.

Comment: And I like the fact that you still left the contents of the initial answer in there because it does provide useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Css :

```
.spinEffect{
  -webkit-animation: spin 0.5s infinite linear;
}
```

jQuery :

```
$(function(){
    $(".whatIsClicked").click(function(){
        $("#yourDiv").addClass("spinEffect");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple script  like this.

Script:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".btn.btn-link" ).click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass( "rotate" );
    });
})
```

css:-

```
.rotate{  
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

html:-

```
<div class="form-group">
    <ul class="list-inline">
        <li><button class="btn btn-link"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></button></li>
        <li><h5>category</h5></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Hope it eill work for you!